# code block does not show in excerpt

Tags: block-editor, excerpt, code

I am creating some blog pages with example codes, and I would like to show the codes in excerpts, but WordPress automatically excludes code blocks from excerpts, is there a workaround for showing code blocks in the excerpt?

Answer (score 0):

Try getting it in raw form from the DB:

```
global $wpdb;
$post_excerpt = $wpdb->get_var(
        $wpdb->prepare(
            "SELECT post_excerpt FROM $wpdb->posts
             WHERE ID = %d
            ",
            $post->ID
        )
    );
```

Comment: That's assuming WordPress is putting the code blocks into post_excerpt but just filtering them out when reading it from the DB. I'd expect it's the other way around, code isn't written into post_excerpt in the first place.